# jboss client-server app. concurrent user

Tags: java, jboss, monitoring

I have a client-server application. Client app. is a swing application. Server app. is ejb3 based Java EE application and working on JBoss AS 4.2.1.GA. Client and server are communicating with RMI. I want to monitor, how many user is using the application and active clients that are requesting information from server. Is there any monitoring tool in JBoss AS i can use, for example by using web/jmx console etc.

Thanks,

Deger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution is to install the Embedded JOPR solution, it means copy a file on the deploy directory and configure JMX security if needed.

More info:

[Quick and dirt page with installation guide](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/embeddedjopr)

[Main page of the project](http://www.jboss.org/embjopr)

Comment: Thanks in advance Massimo, Embedded JOPR is even beyond my expectations. Great tool...